# ASP.net Identity SecurityStampValidator OnValidateIdentity regenerateIdentity parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

Can anyone explain why the `ApplicationUser` class creates the following helper function?

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User, int> manager)
{
    // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    // Add custom user claims here
    return userIdentity;
}
```

The only place I can find it being used is in the **Startup.Auth.cs** file, as the `regenerateIdentity` callback parameter for the  `SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateEntity` function:

```
OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User, int>(
     validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
     regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
     getUserIdCallback: (id) => id.GetUserId<int>())
```

As you can see from the helper it just turns around and calls `manager.CreatedIdentityAsync`. Is there a reason they "polluted" the `ApplicationUser` class with the helper method rather than setting up `OnValidateEntity` as follows?

```
OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User, int>(
     validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
     regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie),
     getUserIdCallback: (id) => id.GetUserId<int>())
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Editted for clarity and simplicity

By abstracting the Identity Generation method into the user class, We are allowed a point of extensibility.

Imagine a scenario in which your application has several different user types, each one would be able to implement their own regeneration logic without having to have separate authentication types. Take the helper method in the ApplicationUser subclass of IdentityUser base class.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{      
    public string NickName {get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDay {get; set;}


    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

We can now separate our claims into different user classes without having to modify the OWIN authentication pipeline, or create a new CookieAuthenticationProvider for each type simply by subclassing the base IdentityUser.

tldr;

It pushes the identity regeneration responsibilities onto the user class that is being regenerated. Similar to a factory method pattern.